# How to find the first qualified document in mongodb using java?

Tags: java, mongodb

How to find the first matching document in mongodb

I try to find matching document in mongodb collection. And I'm sure that there is only one matching document. But when I use the function find() in java, it tries to find all documents(if there were more) in a collection, which will make it slow.

Here is the code I wrote

```java
Document documentForClassMessage=class_message.find(Filters.eq("class_id",class_id)).first();
```

Note: class_message's type is `MongoCollection<Document>`

I thought there would be a method `findOne()` in java since it exits in other language, but it didn't.

I want to know how to find one matching document in a collection and immediately finish searching when it have found or is there a faster way to search a matching document in a large collection?

Comment: have to tried `limit`? I dont know what you are using in java, but its a standard mongodb option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MongoDb Java docs](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/)

> The find().first() construct is useful for queries that should only match a single document or if you are interested in the first document only.

The difference between limit and first is that limit will give you a cursor (you need to iterate over it to get document), while first will return the document itself.

Comment: Will `find().first()` iterate the whole document and then return the first doucment? I'm afraid it will slow down the speed... I want to know which way is faster

Comment: Internally (at DB level) both first() and limit(1) will work the same way. In both cases, the search will stop whenever a  single document is matched. So speed will be the same in both cases. The difference is the object returned, limit(1) will return a list with one document, while first() will directly return that one document.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `limit`?

```
class_message.find(Filters.eq("class_id",class_id)).limit(1)
```

I'm not completely sure about the syntax, as I haven't tried it in java.

[Reference](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html#limit-int-)